# is it possible to make Qtcreator target as directfb instead of X11

Tags: qt, directfb

my target to display output is directfb window. i need to develop an qt application. i found developing application in qtcreator is much easier but problem is output will be seen on X11 window. can any one tell me is there way to get it executed on directfb window. i have no search results for this in google. plz help me

i am using xubuntu

thanks

regards
rashmi

Comment: For the close voter, I'm not sure how asking about compilation is off topic for a programming Q&A site.

Comment: hey thanks for your help i could change build settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to tools->options->qt4
 add qt version you have installed in my case qt-4.7 i.e,
qt4 version= qt-4.7.0
path to qmake is /path to qt directory/bin/qmake

then rebuild.

you are done with changes you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In Creator, you should be able to change your build target to a specific version of Qt.  First, see if the [simulator target](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-building-targets.html) for recent Creator versions will cover you.  If not, you'll need to download and compile the Qt embedded version you want to target.  Then, add that version as one of the Qt Versions and [change your build settings](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-build-settings.html) to use that version of Qt.

Comment: i have qt-4.7.0 installed. which is configured for embedded x86 platform. so now how do i change build settings in Qtcreator.

Comment: When you build the Qt4 version you'll also want to tell it to use directfb by either the -qt-gfx-directfb or -plugin-gfx-directfb when you configure Qt4.  See: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-maemo-4.6/qt-embeddedlinux-directfb.html